# How would I split a form into multiple pages?

Tags: activeadmin

I currently have a resource with a rather large amount of attributes and relations that I need to be able to modify from its respective resource page.

The page itself has become large and unwieldy.  I am wondering if there is a simple way to divide into multiple pages.

For example, 1 page to modify the resource attributes, 1 page to modify its relations to a certain table, another to modify its relations to another table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use AA from master you can give a try to tabs

https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/5-forms.md#tabs

It can help you to separate form visually.